# knokout.js установка контекста в шаблоне

Tags: javascript, knockoutjs

Есть огромный шаблон с использованием цикла, но цикл не имеет смысла использовать т.к. так всегда будет 1 элемент. Как убрать использование цикла без переписывания всего шаблона и указания `info`?

есть

```html
<div data-bind="foreach: info">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    ....
</div>
```

нужно (но, без добавления info)

```html
<div>
    <span data-bind="text: info.title"></span>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

```html
<div data-bind="with: info">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    ....
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Если *info* - это `observableArray`, то:

```html
<div data-bind="with: info()[0]">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    ....
</div>
```

если простой массив, то:

```html
<div data-bind="with: info[0]">
    <span data-bind="text: title"></span>
    ....
</div>
```